# please help me understand the pattern match in haskell. i'm a little confused

Tags: haskell, list, design-patterns, match

if i have somthing like that:

```
func (x1:x2:x3:xs) = xs
```

then `x1,x2,x3` must exist, yes?
they can't be `[]`, but must(again, MUST) be with a value, yes?
also, the `xs` can be `[]` or `[a]` or `[a,a,a]` (etc'), yes?
(in `[a]` i mean that it's a list with one number, and `[a,a,a]` is list of three numbers).

also i have function that define isPrefixOf:

```
myIsPrefixOf :: (Eq a) => [a] -> [a] -> Bool
[]     `myIsPrefixOf`  []      = True
[]     `myIsPrefixOf`  (x:xs)  = True
list   `myIsPrefixOf`  []      = False
(l:ls) `myIsPrefixOf`  (x:xs)  = if l == x then ls `myIsPrefixOf` xs
                                 else False
```

if i remove the first pattern, that the function will look like this:

```
myIsPrefixOf :: (Eq a) => [a] -> [a] -> Bool
[]     `myIsPrefixOf`  (x:xs)  = True
list   `myIsPrefixOf`  []      = False
(l:ls) `myIsPrefixOf`  (x:xs)  = if l == x then ls `myIsPrefixOf` xs
                                 else False
```

and now i will write:

```
[] `myIsPrefixOf` []
```

i will get:  False(it should be True).
is it because that the first pattern has in his right side element: `(x:xs)`, and because of that, `x` MUST be with a value, therefore i pass through the first pattern, and get to the second pattern:

```
list   `myIsPrefixOf`  []      = False
```

which match, and return False.
am i right?

if i'm right, then the difference is that if i write `(x:xs)`,  `x` MUST be a value and NOT `[]`.
on the other hand, if i write `list`, it can be match against `[]` and `[a]` and `[a,a,a]` (etc'), and because of that, `list` of the second pattern, will match to the the first  `[]` in my input, and therefore i'll get False ?
(as before, in `[a]` i mean that it's a list with one number, and `[a,a,a]` is list of three numbers).

also, to correct this situation, i need to replace:

```
[]     myIsPrefixOf  (x:xs)  = True
```

with that:

```
[]     `myIsPrefixOf`  list  = True
```

and now the expressions:

```
[] `myIsPrefixOf` []
[] `myIsPrefixOf` [1,2,3]
```

will both match agains:

```
 [] `myIsPrefixOf` list = True
```

hope i'm right on those things, and now for another question:
here is the fixed function from the start(after applying the changes)

```
myIsPrefixOf :: (Eq a) => [a] -> [a] -> Bool
[]     `myIsPrefixOf`  list  = True
list   `myIsPrefixOf`  []      = False
(l:ls) `myIsPrefixOf`  (x:xs)  = if l == x then ls `myIsPrefixOf` xs
                                 else False
```

now, if i remove the second pattern match, that the function will look like this:

```
myIsPrefixOf :: (Eq a) => [a] -> [a] -> Bool
[]     `myIsPrefixOf`  list  = True
(l:ls) `myIsPrefixOf`  (x:xs)  = if l == x then ls `myIsPrefixOf` xs
                                 else False
```

and call the function like that:

```
[1,2] `myIsPrefixOf` [1]
```

i get an error that said there is no exhaustive patterns in the function.
i want to see if i understand why it is happening.
the function pass through the first pattern and get to the second one:

```
(l:ls) `myIsPrefixOf` (x:xs) = if l == x then ls `myIsPrefixOf` xs
                               else False
```

so:

```
[1,2] `myIsPrefixOf` [1]
```

and:
`l == x`.
they both `1`, so i match again the second pattern:

```
(2:[]) `myIsPrefixOf` ([]:[])
```

now, `l == 2`, but `x == []`
and because that, the expression: `l == x` returns the no-exhaustive pattern...
is it because i'm trying to check for equality between a number and a list?
the equality parameter (==) should check only elements that are in the same type?
(i.e. : `'a' == 'b'` or `1 == 3`)

well, do i understand it all right? :-)
thanks a lot :-).

Comment: Is Haskell your first functional programming language?  I do love Haskell, but a lot of the basic ideas it uses are easier to pick up in other, simpler languages.  In Lisp, `(list 1 2 3)` is really `(cons 1 (cons 2 (cons 3 nil)))`; in ML, `[1,2,3]` is really `1 :: 2 :: 3 :: nil`; Haskell's list construction follows this functional tradition, and so `[1,2,3]` is really `1 : 2 : 3 : []`.

Comment: Great, I hope you continue on your path to functional enlightenment :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your understanding of the first problem is correct, but your understanding of the second problem is not.

To see why, step back from actual function a bit and look at lists. Lists have two constructors, `[]` and `:`. So a complete pattern match needs to cover both cases.

Your function has two list arguments, so you need to cover `2 * 2 == 4` cases. This will *always* be the case for a function that takes two list arguments; if you leave one combination out, you will get the "non-exhaustive patterns" error for some inputs. Those are the cases you have in your first version:

```
[] `f` [] = True
[] `f` (x:xs) = True
(l:ls) `f` [] = False
(l:ls) `f` (x:xs) = ...
```

When you avoid pattern matching on the two list constructors, you can collapse two cases into one. That's what you did in your first question:

```
[] `f` list = True
...
```

Here you are ignored the details of the second argument--it doesn't matter which list constructor it is. Collapsing it like this works as long as the answer for both cases is the same, which it is in this case.

---

For your second question, you want to drop the third case. The only way to avoid the "non-exhaustive patterns" error is to make the fourth case less specific:

```
(l:ls) `f` xlist = ...
```

But then you're stuck, because you can't get at the first element of `xlist` anymore, because you don't know that it's not empty. You could do `head xlist`, but that'll crash on empty lists. So actually you have to check for the empty list first:

```
(l:ls) `f` xlist = if null xlist then False 
                   else if l == head xlist then ls `myIsPrefixOf` tail xlist
                   else False
```

But that's so verbose that the original pattern match is better.

---

The specific way that you went wrong in your second question is in the manual execution of `isPrefixOf [1,2] [1]`.

> the function pass through the first pattern and get to the second one:
>
> ```
> (l:ls) `myIsPrefixOf` (x:xs) = if l == x then ls `myIsPrefixOf` xs
>                                else False
> ```
>
> so:
>
> ```
> [1,2] `myIsPrefixOf` [1]
> ```
>
> and:
>
> ```
> l == x.
> ```

Good so far.

> they both 1, so i match again the second pattern:

Wait, hold on a minute to figure out all the values here. We already know that `l==x==1`. But also `ls==[2]` and `xs==[]`.

Now when we recur, `ls` won't match the first pattern (it's not empty), but `xs` won't match the second pattern (it's empty, and `(x:xs)` requires a `:` object, not `[]`). So the function crashes with 'non-exhaustive pattern'.

Answer (score 4):

This seems to be a common misunderstanding for people learning Haskell. The `:` construct is not list concatenation. Hence, `x:xs` doesn't match "a list of things named `x` followed by a list of things named `xs`". Instead, think of `:` as if it were named `StartsAListThatContinues`.

Similarly, The `[]` construct doesn't mean "I don't care" or "some list, whatever". Think of it as if it were named `NoMore`.

Now, imagine your original code was then:

```
myIsPrefixOf :: (Eq a) => [a] -> [a] -> Bool
NoMore                            `myIsPrefixOf`  NoMore                             = True
NoMore                            `myIsPrefixOf`  (x `StartsAListThatContinues` xs)  = True
list                              `myIsPrefixOf`  NoMore                             = False
(l `StartsAListThatContinues` ls) `myIsPrefixOf`  (x `StartsAListThatContinues` xs)  = if l == x then ls `myIsPrefixOf` xs
```

Finally, realize that a list can either be `NoMore` or a `StartsAListThatContinues` structure. One or the the other, and that's all it can be.

Under these conditions, perhaps it is clear how your code can be reduced (remembering that `_` means "I don't care"):

```
myIsPrefixOf :: (Eq a) => [a] -> [a] -> Bool
NoMore                            `myIsPrefixOf`  _                                  = True
list                              `myIsPrefixOf`  NoMore                             = False
(l `StartsAListThatContinues` ls) `myIsPrefixOf`  (x `StartsAListThatContinues` xs)  = if l == x then ls `myIsPrefixOf` xs
```

And then

```
myIsPrefixOf :: (Eq a) => [a] -> [a] -> Bool
NoMore                            `myIsPrefixOf`  _                                  = True
_                                 `myIsPrefixOf`  NoMore                             = False
(l `StartsAListThatContinues` ls) `myIsPrefixOf`  (x `StartsAListThatContinues` xs)  = if l == x then ls `myIsPrefixOf` xs
```

Comment: thanks for your comment :-).
i think after all the comments, i understand it (hopefully)  :-).

Answer (score 1):

Your understanding is mostly correct, but you do seem to have some problems. When you have a list, say `list`, that you're matching with `x:xs`, then both `list` and `xs` are of list type, but `x` is of the element type of the list. So it is not possible for `x` to equal `[]` unless you have a list of lists, which these examples don't have.

So, in your second example, in the call

```
[1,2] `myIsPrefixOf` [1]
```

the recursive call after matching the `1`s is

```
[2] `myIsPrefixOf` []
```

(that is, the right-hand side is not `[]:[]`, which would be the same as `[[]]`, a one element list whose only element is the empty list) and you don't have a pattern that matches with the first parameter being non-empty and the second being empty.

Comment: thanks.
so every time i have one element left i.e. `[a]` , when i go into recursion and get his "`xs`" , i'll always get `[]`?
for instance: `(x:xs)` and i only have `x` that is `1`, so it's `(1:[])` and the "`xs`" is `[]`?